# How to set 2 arguments on Let function in a class in vba (for excel)?

Tags: vba, class

I am creating a Class in vba (for excel) to process blocks of data. After some manipulation of a text file I end up with blocks of data (variable asdatablock() ) which I want to process in a For Loop

I created my own Class called ClDataBlock from which I can get key data by a simple call of the property required.  1st pass seems to work and I am now trying to expand my Let function to 2 argument but it’s not working. **How do I specify the 2nd argument?**

```
Dim TheDataBlock As New ClDataBlock
For i = 0 to UBound(asdatablock)
    asDataBlockLine = Split(asdatablock(i), vbLf)   ‘ split block into line
    TheDataBlock.LineToProcess = asDataBlockLine(5) ‘allocate line to process by the class
    Dvariable1 = TheDataBlock.TheVariable1
    ‘and so on for the key variables needed base don the class properties defined
Next i
```

In the Class Module the Let function takes 2 arguments

### Public Property Let LineToProcess(stheline As String, sdataneeded As String)

code extract of what I am looking at - 
'in the class module

```
Dim pdMass As Double
Private pthelineprocessed As String

Public Property Let LineToProcess(stheline As String, sdataneeded As String)

 pthelineprocessed = DeleteSpaces(Replace(stheline, vbLf, ""))

    Dim aslinedatafield() As String

    Select Case sdataneeded

    'THIS IS AN EXTRACT FROM THE FUNCTION
    'THERE ARE AS NUMBER OF CASES WHICH ARE DEALT WITH

    Case Is = "MA"
            aslinedatafield() = Split(pthelineprocessed, " ")
            pdbMass = CDbl(aslinedatafield(2))

    End select

End function

Public Property Get TheMass() As Double
    TheMass = pdMass
End Property
```

'in the "main" module

```
Dim TheDataBlock As New ClDataBlock
For i = 0 to UBound(asdatablock)
 TheDataBlock.LineToProcess = asDataBlockLines(5) 'Need to pass argument "MA" as well
 dmass = TheDataBlock.TheMass
'and so on for all the data to be extracted
 Next i
```

Comment: `sDataNeeded` isn't a keyword. It's an argument or a parameter, depending upon which side you are looking from. To set the property you need `ClDataBlock.LineToProcess("This is my Line", "This is the data I need")` somewhere in a standard code module. With the help of these two parameters `ClDataBlock` must be able to set the property to the value you want. You can then extract the value found with a `Property Get` call. You will have to give us much more code in order to get a more helpful response.

Comment: Thanks. Will try again but I f I define TheDataBlock.LineToProcess( asDataBlockLine(5),"X") then I get a syntax error

Comment: I think I may revise the code to pass the entire string block to the Class and do the split line in the class. While this does not "fix" my problem it might be more logical.. Will read something like: TheDataBlock.ProcessData(asdatablock(i),"X")

Comment: You may get the syntax error because the "as" in `TheDataBlock.LineToProcess( asDataBlockLine(5),"X")`. Or because you try to call a sub in the class. Processing may not be the final goal. Perhaps you will want to receive the product of the process back. Then you will need to use `Property Get`.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the "correct" way of setting up the Let function with 2 arguments and calling it from the "main" Sub?

Comment: I like to learn from Chip Pearson. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Classes.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Property has 2 or more arguments, the last argument is what is getting assigned.  In other words, the syntax is like this:

```
TheDataBlock.LineToProcess("MA") = asDataBlockLine(5)
```

This means you need to change the signature of your property:

```
Public Property Let LineToProcess(sdataneeded As String, stheline As String)
```

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your updated question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciated. The "Class" approach keeps the overall program a bit easier to read. May go ahead with this approach for all the cases ie data to extract